# WebGL fragment shader pixel position

Tags: shaders, webgl

I have written a fragment shader, on a shape which is a square made with `gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP`, and which displays a radar:

[image]

To build the radar, I'm using distance from the center of the shape.

Currently, I'm using `gl_FragCoord` and have to pass the shader the size of the window, the position of the center of the radar, in order to determine where I am in the shape. I'm not really OK with that..

I would like to know if there is a better way to make the shader, to make it independent from display variables.

For example I thought I could use `gl_PointCoord` whose x and y coordinates goes from 0. to 1., but it requires to use `GL_POINTS`... I could give it a try by using `GL_POINTS`, but I'm not sure it's THE best solution.

For example, I could make a 3d scene, with lot of cubes, and display this radar on the faces of that cube. If the shader isn't independent from `gl_FragCoord`, it feels like it will be a nightmare to make it work.

Is there a way to get the relative position of the pixel we are giving the color, in the shape (triangle) we are rendering?
Do you have suggestions / tips?

Comment: Why not use UV coordinates? You do need to pass them to the shader, but they're probably your best choice

Comment: Yes it's what I'm looking for. To do this, I think that I need to pass fake textureCoordinates to my shader, and use vTextureCoord.st which should be interpolated inside the fragment shader. Is it like that ?

Comment: Thanks, your sentence helped me to understand that "varying" variables were interpolated for each pixel rendered in the fragment shader, and that I could use it. I sent a "texture coordinate" array to the shader, and now it's rendering correctly :) You can write an answer.